# Connection to host xxxxxxxxxx at port 22 connection timed out

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I am trying to set up my raspberry pi4 using ssh on windows 11 but I cannot connect to it and keep getting port 22 connection timed out. I can't even type in IP address on my browser now and access anything. I need help please. I lost my known_hosts file with my keys and since then I can't access anything via ssh be it ethernet cabled or wifi

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the pi was not working before, as you are just trying to set it up.  So, just for completeness (based on my frustrations with it)

1. Check that the power supply is adequate, it is best to use the official power supply
2. Check that you have you loaded an OS on the sdcard.  Remove it and check on Windows.  If the power supply is inadequate it can destroy the sdcard
3. Check that you have the correct ipaddress (it can be set as static in the configuration).  Check on your router or a tool such as Fing/Finger

Comment: The pi is currently being powered by a pisugar 3. But I have also plugged it in with the official plug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the connection timeout at port 22 and the missing known_hosts file, complicating matters further. Verify the network connection first, make sure both Windows 11 and Raspberry Pi4 share the same network. Wi-Fi? Double-check. Ethernet cable? Ensure proper plug-in.

Now, SSH on your Pi4 must be enabled; it's a must. Check settings via display or enable it fresh through Raspberry Pi Configuration. Don't sweat the missing known_hosts file; it'll regenerate when you SSH connect again. Watch out for Windows firewall or any pesky antivirus software. They might block the connection, causing timeouts. If accessing via the browser still fails, give both machines a good ol' reboot.